# Can a controller act as both a regulator and a servo?

Tags: control-theory

I was asked a weird question today: can a controller act as both a regulator and a servo in a control system? I think these two roles are essentially not contradictory. However, I do need a more detailed answer to this question.

Comment: Is this really a mathematics question?

Comment: It's technically an electrical engineering question.

Comment: When we talk about the controller, we often think about signals: take these input signals, perform some calculations, feed that signal to output. When we talk about servo, we often think about sensor+controller+actuator, i.e., for servos, we mix signals level and physical action. Thus, the question you ask is a question of your definitions of controller and servo.